# Would the low voltage of lithium ion batteries in series be just the number in series times the cutoff voltage for a single battery?

Tags: batteries

I'm trying to use two 18v lithium-ion batteries in series to power a 36V motor. I'm going to use a cut-off circuit like this (https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07929Y5SZ/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza) to shut the load off before the batteries are ruined. It's my understanding that a safe low voltage for these batteries is 16.5v so can I assume that setting the low voltage cutoff to 33v when they're in series will protect them?

Comment: No, that thing is for Lead Acid battery.

Comment: "DC12-36V lead acid battery and lithium ion battery."

Comment: Oops, sorry. If it says so, why would I be against? :-) It is protection, and only for protection, meaning cut off at set voltage, right? That sounds something to avoid.

Comment: Okay, a second thought, since there are not many alternative ideas: Use one each, cut at 16.5V. Charge using lithium-ion charger. Did you check if the batteries have BMS?

Answer (score 2):

Not really, and you will need some kind of balancing (or cutoff protection that senses each battery's voltage independently). The two battery packs will not have exactly the same capacity, and by the time they both reach a low enough voltage to cut off, one pack could be deeply discharged to the point of damage.

However, if these are already 18 V battery *packs*, they may have built-in protection or other intelligent battery management (balancing the handful of cells within each pack). You'll need to investigate their datasheets to see. After all, the same principle applies for the individual cells -- if they are out of balance, each needs to be tracked independently for cutoff.